# How to replace the characters by * in a specified column dynamically in ssis package?

Tags: ssis

I have an Excel source with one of the column name `Emailid`.

I want the output like below example:

```
'mahesh123@gmail.com'
```

The output should be

```
'ma*****23@gmail.com'
```

As a beginner i am searching for the replacement for function `STUFF`, in SSIS package...

```
select 
substring(studentEMAILIDid,1,2)
+ replicate('*',len(substring(studentEMAILIDid,1,
       charindex(studentEMAILIDid,'@')
  -1‌​)-4) 
+ substring(studentEMAILIDid,charindex(studentEMAILIDid,'@')-2,2) 
+ substring(studentEMAILIDid,charindex(studentEMAILIDid,'@')+1,
len(studentEMAILIDi‌​d) 
from <tablename>
```

I tried the above code in SSMS,i am expecting the result through SSIS package without using "Execute SQL Task".

This is the expression I tried:

```
emailid==
substring(
    StudentEMailID,
    3,
    LEN(right(StudentEMailID,
       findstring('@',Stud‌​entEMailID + '@')-1
       )
    )-4,
    REPLICATE('*',LEN(LEFT(StudentEMailID,
    findstring('@',StudentEMailID + '@')-1))-4)) 
    –
```

Comment: Is that based on locations 3 to 7? what happens if the email is less than 7 characters long? You need to be more specific. Also please post the expression that you have tried so far.

Comment: actually its a column in excel file. As a beginner i am searching for the replacement for function "STUFF", in SSIS package...select 
substring(studentEMAILIDid,1,2)+
replicate('*',len(substring(studentEMAILIDid,1,charindex(studentEMAILIDid,'@')-1)-4) +
substring(studentEMAILIDid,charindex(studentEMAILIDid,'@')-2,2)
+ substring(studentEMAILIDid,charindex(studentEMAILIDid,'@')+1,len(studentEMAILIDid)
from <tablename>.I tried the above code in SSMS,i am expecting the result through SSIS package without using "Execute SQL Task".  Thanks for your reply

Comment: In SSIS you have to create an Excel source and a OLE DB (or ADO.Net) connection to your SQL Server, then put a derived column in the data flow, then put a SSIS expression in there to convert the value. Start with a very simple expression and work your way up. In the SSIS expression editor you will see both `SUBSTRING` and `REPLICATE` under the string functions folder.

Comment: i tried with those functions but unable to write the expression..Please can you help me out with the expression

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the expression that you tried.

Comment: emailid==substring(StudentEMailID,3,LEN(right(StudentEMailID,findstring('@',StudentEMailID + '@')-1))-4,REPLICATE('*',LEN(LEFT(StudentEMailID,findstring('@',StudentEMailID + '@')-1))-4))

Comment: All the detail you have added, I have added to your original question. However I am not going to try and comb through the expression your posted. I suggest you do it bit by bit and build it up. It would help if you indicated what that expression returns - an error or an unexpected output?

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
select N'mahesh123@gmail.com' as email
union all
select N'EmpireAgain@gmail.com'
```

Derived Column Code:

```
SUBSTRING(email,1,2) + 
REPLICATE("*",LEN(email) - FINDSTRING(email,"@",1) - 4) + 
SUBSTRING(email,FINDSTRING(email,"@",1)-2,LEN(email)-(FINDSTRING(email,"@",1)-2) + 1)
```

Result:

```
email                   NewEmail
mahesh123@gmail.com     ma*****23@gmail.com
EmpireAgain@gmail.com   Em*****in@gmail.com
```